# How to open a particular accordion based click event in reactjs and autoclose remaining accordion?

Tags: reactjs

**I want to open a particular Section on clicking on that. How to do that by using click event? And also auto close the remaining accordion if I click on another accordion. Here is my code.**

***Accordion Component***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Section from './section';

class Accordion extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            open: false,
            headingClassName: 'accordion-heading',
            className: 'accordion-content accordion-close',
            Label: 'label-close',
            icon: "+",
            selectedItem: null,
        };
    }

    handleClick = () => {

        const open = this.state.open;
        if (open) {
            this.setState({
                open: false,
                className: "accordion-content accordion-close",
                headingClassName: "accordion-heading",
                Label: 'label-close',
                icon: "+",

            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                open: true,
                className: "accordion-content accordion-open",
                headingClassName: "accordion-heading clicked",
                Label: 'label-open',
                icon: "-",
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="accordion-container">
                <h1>Accordian Component</h1>
```

> How to pass id as parameter in each section in onClick event to open
>   particular accordion and to autoclose remaining.

```
     <Section>
                    <div className={this.state.headingClassName} onClick={this.handleClick} id="1">
                        <h3>One</h3> <label className={this.state.Label}>{this.state.icon}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className={this.state.className}>
                        <p>This is paragraph</p>
                    </div>
                </Section>
                <Section>
                    <div className={this.state.headingClassName} onClick={this.handleClick} id="2">
                        <h3>Two</h3> <label className={this.state.Label}>{this.state.icon}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className={this.state.className}>
                        <p>This is paragraph</p>
                    </div>
                </Section>
                <Section>
                    <div className={this.state.headingClassName} onClick={this.handleClick} id="3">
                        <h3>Three</h3> <label className={this.state.Label}>{this.state.icon}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className={this.state.className}>
                        <p>This is paragraph</p>
                    </div>
                </Section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Accordion;
```

***Section Component***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Section extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="parent-accordion"> 
                {this.props.children}           
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Section;
```

***CSS***

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.accordion-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 700px;
}

.accordion-container h1 {
  color: #0000007a;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.parent-accordion {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1.5px solid #00000017;
}

.accordion-heading {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background-color: #e2e2e254;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  /* font-size: 17px; */
  /* font-weight: 600; */
  color: #2b2b41;
  /* font-family: sans-serif; */
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

.accordion-heading:hover {
  background-color: #000000c7;
  color: white;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all i've encompased a **minimal** (no css) example of how an accordion would behave on codesandbox, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/3qxp7m5mnm).

This can be done multiple ways. In the example above the body of the `tab` is hidden with `display:none` if the tab is not active.Basically you iterate over your data in the `render` function and that's where you set your classes based on whatever flags you want (in your case `isActive`). You could render a Section for each tab and pass props to it.

The click handler updates your state with the id of the active tab.